# Adjunct professor capacities

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, advisor

Can I mention an adjunct professor as my proposed supervisor for graduate studies, or adjunct  professors are not allowed to be supervisor?

Are there anythings that I should be aware of before mentioning his/her name in my application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve this question is to e-mail the person and ask whether they anticipate taking new graduate students in the near future.  This is worth asking even for non-adjunct faculty (since they may have all the students they can handle already, they may be retiring soon or moving to another university or an administrative position, etc.), so nobody will be surprised or take offense at the question.

As for what sort of answer to expect, it depends on what sort of adjunct professor it is.  Sometimes researchers from other institutions (government or industrial research labs, museums, etc.) hold adjunct positions at universities.  They may or may not be allowed to supervise graduate students, depending on the terms of their appointment, but it's common to allow this; often it's part of the point of the position.  On the other hand, there's another sort of position sometimes called adjunct faculty, namely low-paid temporary workers hired to teach introductory courses, and these jobs are not likely to involve graduate supervision.  You should be able to tell pretty easily which case applies to any particular person by looking on the web, and in any case e-mailing them (as described above) will give a definitive answer.

Comment: Your answer is great, but unfortunately many professors don't reply to emails (talking from experience) therefore I asked the question just to make sure that adjunct professors can or can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know “in principle”, look at your university's policies… This is something they decide. For example, the [University of Manitoba](http://umanitoba.ca/faculties/graduate_studies/admin/adjunct_information.html) says:

> a) The Adjunct Professor may be thesis/practicum supervisor or co-supervisor of, or serve on the thesis/practicum committee for, graduate students registered in the Faculty of Graduate Studies. In the event that the appointment of an Adjunct Professor expires before the graduate students have completed their programs, the Head of the department/unit shall be responsible for recommending reappointment or naming a replacement.

Whether it's a good idea is an entirely different question…

Comment: So Adjunct Professor abilities differ from one university to another, depending on the university's policies.

Comment: @TheHiary their abilities depend on each individual, but their official capacities (what they are allowed to do) depends on each institution's policy